# why pygraphviz layout() move the nodes which has 'pin = true'?

Tags: vector-graphics

my code :

```
A.layout('neato', args='-Gsep=+250 -Gsplines=ortho -Goverlap=false')
A.draw('1.svg')

#do something, add new nodes with pos to A,
add_some_nodes_to_A()

for node in A.nodes():
    node.attr['pos'] += '!'
    node.attr['pin'] = 'true'
A.layout('neato', args='-Gsep=+250 -Gsplines=ortho -Goverlap=false - Gnotranslate=true')
A.draw('2.svg')
```

1.svg :

[image]

2.svg :

[image]

before the second layout, all A's nodes have pined, why the nodes move in 2.svg?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an end-user question about using graphics software, not about graphics algorithms or research.